# Extracting string array from object array

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist, adapter

So I have arraylist `modelData`  that populates a recyclerview using sqlite database in some activity.!
Now in my `MainActivity` I want an string arraylist of names from the `modelData` !

that's what did so far..

```
 // inside the onCreate of MainActivity 

//code ..
db = new DBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
modelData = new ArrayList<AzkarModel>();
modelData = db.getDataFromDB();

for (AzkarModel o : modelData) {
   ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
   names.add(o.getName());
}

for (int i = 0; i< modelData.size();i++){
  names.add(modelData.get(i).getName());
 Log.i("The List Log", names);

}
```

**Two problems**

**1)  [FIXED]** The `names` arraylist is showing the same element twice at first and end

```
  I/ The List Log: [Mike, John, Sam, Nora, Mike]
```

**2)** The arraylist `names` doesn't get updated..! when I add/edit/delete from the recycler and go back to the `MainActivity` I don't see the new changes unless I close the app then open it again..! I can't use `notifyDataSetChanged` since there's no adapter here.!

Comment: why are you creating new object of aarylist in for loop?

Comment: Please post the correct code, this is not going to compile because a scope issue in the for loop with: ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: @DivyeshPatel I'll fix that

Comment: see the update guys

Comment: First off, your AzkarModel simply have two models with same name. That's on you, it is not related to the code you posted in here (or not yet). Secondly, `onCreate` indeed means that this is done only once when app is created. If you want a live list, then you shold have this code elsewhere.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov what do u mean that `AzkarModel` have two models with same name!? I have  a model class called  `AzkarModel` and has name variable with setters and getters and it connected to the db..!! 
I think you don't understand me correctly..read the question again to know why I used this code inside MainActivity

Comment: nevermind ,, I found a solution.. you are right.. I moved the code from onCreate to onResume instead and works now..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have an array list object, populate it inside a loop

```
ArrayList<String> modelNames = new ArrayList<>();

for (AzkarModel model : modelData) {
    modelNames.add(model.getName());
}
```

Now you have an array list with model names inside. Concerning the second question, please use an recyclerview adapter [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview) you can find a nice tutorial.